# How to lock a file when opening files?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I would like to perform the following, but when I compiled and ran the source code, the file does not lock afterwards.

Can anyone solve this problem?

Here is the source code:

```
    Private Sub CopyProtectFileButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CopyProtectFileButton.Click

    Dim FileSt As FileStream = New FileStream("C:\Users\John\Desktop\NoteThisOne.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write)

    Try
        FileSt.Lock(0, 64)
        Console.WriteLine("Locked")
    Catch Ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(Ex.Message)
    End Try
    FileSt.Close()


End Sub
```

Comment: Are you expecting that the file on the hard drive will become permanently read-only after executing FileStream.Lock?

Comment: As soon as you `Close` the `FileStream` you are releasing the lock.  What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

since your question missing some info.

- i use the following code to `block/unblock` executable files (`*.exe`)
- Fucntion to call in my case a `button_click`

> AddFileSecurity(fileloc,domainAndUserName,FileSystemRights.ExecuteFile,AccessControlType.Deny)

- `fileloc` is `aboslute/path/to/exefile.exe`
- `domainAndUserName` is the domain of the computer in short(`yourComputerName/UserAccountName`), and it can be get from

> domainAndUserName = Environment.UserDomainName & "\" & Environment.UserName

```
  Sub AddFileSecurity(ByVal fileName As String, ByVal account As String, _
    ByVal rights As FileSystemRights, ByVal controlType As AccessControlType)
    Try
      '"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
        Dim fSecurity As FileSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(fileName)
        Dim accessRule As FileSystemAccessRule = New FileSystemAccessRule(account, rights, AccessControlType.Deny)
        fSecurity.AddAccessRule(accessRule)
        File.SetAccessControl(fileName, fSecurity)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

- THIS WILL BLOCK OPENING OF ANY EXE FILE
- TO UNBLOCK

> RemoveFileSecurity(fileLoc, domainAndUserName,
>   FileSystemRights.ExecuteFile, AccessControlType.Deny)
>
> ```
> Sub RemoveFileSecurity(ByVal fileName As String, ByVal account As String, _
>         ByVal rights As FileSystemRights, ByVal controlType As AccessControlType)
>         Dim fSecurity As FileSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(fileName)
>         fSecurity.RemoveAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(account, rights, controlType))
>         File.SetAccessControl(fileName, fSecurity)
>  End Sub
> ```